# Time is running out to earn your Beta Badge!

Tags: discussion, badges

You have a *once-in-a-lifetime opportunity* to earn a Beta Badge for OR.SE! Beta Badges are earned for participation in the private beta phase (and are awarded once we move into public beta). The exact requirements for Beta Badges are a little unclear; they are either:

> - silver; awarded once
> - Participate actively in a site’s private beta phase by:
>
>   - Voting 10 times
>   - Adding 3 posts with score > 0
>   - Visiting the site on 3 separate days
> - All three requirements must be met, and met before the public beta begins (or possibly before the badge script runs) [[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/67399#67399)]

or:

> the exact requirements not disclosed to prevent users from just doing the bare minimum [[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81840/504785)]

In either case, it's pretty easy to earn the Beta Badge if you participate just a bit during private beta. But once public beta starts (in about a week, if all goes well), you'll lose your chance forever. Don't squander it!

Comment: Badges? I don;t need no stinkin' badges.                                                                      Some of the SE badges are really stupid. And don't get me started on those asinine hats (which go on your avatar).

Comment: Nobody *needs* badges. But they’re fun!

Comment: This might not be the best place to ask this, but what are we waiting on for the public beta? Are there requirements? Or just a certain amount of time to pass?

Comment: @DavidM. Usually after about 3 weeks, at which point SE staff will have a look to see whether the site is 'ready' (which I'd guess this site would be). See also the discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50672672#50672672).

Comment: @Rob I thought the beta badge was awarded when the site moves to public beta, not when it graduates?

Comment: @Rob I interpreted it as, do your 10 votes, 3 posts, etc during private beta, get the badge once public beta starts, but I could be wrong. Anyway this is not a big deal one way or another — just some added fun and motivation.

Answer (score 3):

[Time is up](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta), 38 got the badge.

[image: Beta Badge]

Comment: Does that mean we are public now? How can one tell?

Comment: Oh -- yes -- we are! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121892/operations-research

Comment: Click your Avatar, then "Network Profile" (upper right), and see that OR is listed.